# Issue with form submission in React Native

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

I initially created a website, and I am currently in the process of developing a similar application in React Native. Both utilize the same backend. I am currently working on creating a form that allows adding a user, but the backend is telling me that all fields are empty upon submission. However, when I console.log before sending to the API, I see that all fields are filled.

```
Backend: 

public function addUser()
{
    $response = array();

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ?? null;
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ?? null;
    $email = $_POST['email'] ?? null;
    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? null;
    $tel = $_POST['tel'] ?? null;
    $address = $_POST['address'] ?? null;
    $role = $_POST['role'] ?? null;

    // Initialisation du tableau pour stocker les champs manquants
    $missingFields = array();

    // Vérification de la présence de tous les champs requis
    if (!$firstname) {
        $missingFields[] = 'firstname';
    }
    if (!$lastname) {
        $missingFields[] = 'lastname';
    }
    if (!$email) {
        $missingFields[] = 'email';
    }
    if (!$password) {
        $missingFields[] = 'password';
    }
    if (!$tel) {
        $missingFields[] = 'tel';
    }
    if (!$address) {
        $missingFields[] = 'address';
    }
    if (!$role) {
        $missingFields[] = 'role';
    }

    if (!empty($missingFields)) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'il Manque : ' . implode(', ', $missingFields) . '.';
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }

    if ($this->userModel->emailExists($email)) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'Erreur : L\'email est déjà utilisé.';
    } else {
        // Ajout de l'utilisateur
        $this->userModel->addUser($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $tel, $address, $role);
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Utilisateur ajouté avec succès.';
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}


Frontend : 

------------------------apiService
   addUser: async (formData) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/users/addUsers`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
    
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP status code: ${response.status}`);
            }
    
            const responseData = await response.json();
    
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Utilisateur ajouté avec succès', responseData.message);
                return responseData; // Retourner les données de la réponse
            } else {
                console.error('Erreur lors de l\'ajout de l\'utilisateur:', responseData.message);
                throw new Error(responseData.message); // Lancer une erreur pour la gérer dans le composant
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi à l\'API:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    },


---------------------


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { apiService } from '../API/ApiService';

const Utilisateur = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [editableUsers, setEditableUsers] = useState({});
    const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
         firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          email: '',
          tel: '',
          address: '',
          role: '' 
        });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(editableUsers);
    }, [editableUsers]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const fetchedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers();
                setUsers(fetchedUsers);
               // console.log(fetchedUsers);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération des utilisateurs :", error);
            }
        };

        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    const handleInputChange = (userId, fieldName, value) => {
        setEditableUsers((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [userId]: {
            ...prev[userId],
            [fieldName]: value === '' ? "" : value,
          },
        }));
      };
      

    const handleUpdateAllUsers = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        let isUpdated = false;
    
        for (const userId in editableUsers) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            const userData = editableUsers[userId];
    
            for (const key in userData) {
                formData.append(key, userData[key]);
            }
    
            try {
                const response = await apiService.updateUser(userId, formData);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    const errorData = await response.json(); // Supposons que le serveur renvoie un JSON même pour les erreurs.
                    throw new Error(`HTTP status code: ${response.status}, Message: ${errorData.message}`);
                }
                
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Réponse de l\'API:', data);
                
                if (data.message === 'Utilisateur mis à jour avec succès.') {
                    isUpdated = true;
                } else {
                    console.error('Erreur lors de la mise à jour de l\'utilisateur', data.message);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi à l\'API', error);
                // Si vous souhaitez traiter l'erreur plus spécifiquement, vous pouvez ici.
            }
        }
    
        if (isUpdated) {
            alert("Modifications ajoutées avec succès");
            const updatedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers();
            setUsers(updatedUsers);
        }
    
        setEditableUsers({});
    };

    const handleDeleteUser = async (userId) => {
        try {
            const response = await apiService.deleteUser(userId);
            console.log('te');
            if (response.status === 204) {
                console.log('Suppression réussie');
                const updatedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers(); // Ajout de cette ligne pour récupérer la liste mise à jour
                setUsers(updatedUsers);
                // Effectuez les actions nécessaires après la suppression
            } else {
                console.error('Réponse inattendue lors de la suppression');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            const updatedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers(); // Ajout de cette ligne pour récupérer la liste mise à jour
            setUsers(updatedUsers);
            console.error('Erreur lors de la suppression', error.message);
        }
    };

    const handleNewUserInputChange = (name, value) => {
        setNewUser({ ...newUser, [name]: value });
    };
    
    

    const handleAddNewUser = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(newUser);

            
        // Créer un objet FormData
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (const key in newUser) {
            formData.append(key, newUser[key]);
        }

    
        try {
            const addUserResponse = await apiService.addUser(formData); // Assurez-vous que addUser gère correctement FormData
            console.log('Réponse de l\'API:', addUserResponse);
            
            // Vérifiez si l'ajout de l'utilisateur a réussi
            if (addUserResponse.success) {
                console.log('Utilisateur ajouté avec succès', addUserResponse.message);
    
                // Réinitialiser le formulaire
                setNewUser({ firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '', tel: '', address: '', role: 'User' });
    
                // Récupérer la liste mise à jour des utilisateurs
                const fetchedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers();
                setUsers(fetchedUsers);
            } else {
                const fetchedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers();
                setUsers(fetchedUsers);
                console.error('Erreur lors de l\'ajout de l\'utilisateur', addUserResponse.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            const fetchedUsers = await apiService.getAllUsers();
            setUsers(fetchedUsers);
            console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi à l\'API', error);
        }
    };
    
    
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.containerGlobalUsers}>
                <View style={styles.containerListUsers}>
                    <View style={styles.listUsers}>
                        {users.map((user) => (
                            <View style={styles.userInfo} key={user.id}>
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Prénom"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.firstname ?? user.firstname}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'firstname', value)}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Nom"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.lastname ?? user.lastname}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'lastname', value)}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.email ?? user.email}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'email', value)}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Téléphone"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.tel ?? user.tel}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'tel', value)}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Adresse"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.address ?? user.address}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'address', value)}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.userInput}
                                    placeholder="Role"
                                    value={editableUsers[user.id]?.role ?? user.role}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => handleInputChange(user.id, 'role', value)}
                                />
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ContainerDeleteUser} onPress={() => handleDeleteUser(user.id)}>
                                    <Text style={styles.btnDeleteUser}>Supprimer</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        ))}
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containerBtnUpdateUser} onPress={handleUpdateAllUsers}>
                            <Text style={styles.btnUpdateUser}>Mettre à jour</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.containerGlobalAddUser}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleUser}>Ajouter un nouvel utilisateur</Text>
                    <View style={styles.containerFormAddUser}>
                        <View style={styles.containerAddUserSectionTop}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Prénom"
                                value={newUser.firstname}
                                name="firstname"
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('firstname', value)}
                                />
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Nom"
                                value={newUser.lastname}
                                name='lastname'
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('lastname', value)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Mail"
                                name="email"
                                value={newUser.email}
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('email', value)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Mot de passe"
                                name="password"
                                value={newUser.password}
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('password', value)}
                            />
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.containerAddUserSectionBottom}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Téléphone"
                                name="tel"
                                value={newUser.tel}
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('tel', value)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Adresse"
                                name="address"
                                value={newUser.address}
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('address', value)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.userInput}
                                placeholder="Role"
                                name="role"
                                value={newUser.role}
                                onChangeText={(value) => handleNewUserInputChange('role', value)}
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.containerButtonAddUser} onPress={handleAddNewUser}>
                                <Text style={styles.btnAddUser}>Ajouter</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerGlobalUsers:{
        height: 1800
    },
    containerListUsers:{
        height: 500
    },
    listUsers:{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        gap: 20,
        width: "100%",
        height:"auto"
    },
    userInfo:{
        width: 300,
        gap: 10
    },
    userInput:{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#FF9A00",
        height: 40,
        width: "100%",
        borderRadius: 10,
        paddingLeft: 20 
    },
    ContainerDeleteUser:{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 30,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    btnDeleteUser:{
        color: "#fff"
    },
    containerBtnUpdateUser:{
        backgroundColor:"#ff9a00",
        marginTop: 15,
        height: 30,
        width: "80%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    btnUpdateUser:{
        color:"#fff"
    },
    containerListUsers:{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    containerGlobalAddUser:{
        height: 500,
    }, 
    titleUser:{
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center",
        marginTop : 30,
        marginBottom: 30
    },
    containerAddUserSectionTop:{
        gap: 10,
        width: "80%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    containerAddUserSectionBottom:{
        gap: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        width: "80%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    containerFormAddUser:{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    containerButtonAddUser:{
        backgroundColor: "#ff9a00",
        height: 30,
        width: "50%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems:"center",
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    btnAddUser:{
        color: "#fff",
    }
})

export default Utilisateur;
```

Comment: I don't see you using the `formData` object, that you are adding the parameters to, anywhere in the requests you are making.

Comment: `const addUserResponse = await apiService.addUser(test);` - and what is `test` supposed to be here?

Comment: @CBroe My apologies for the oversight. Here is the modified code

Comment: _"when I console.log before sending to the API, I see that all fields are filled"_ - what exactly are you referring to here, _what_ did you log?

Comment: @CBroe Console log of newUser before using formData

Comment: Don't know what `apiService.addUser` actually does. When you inspect the request using your browser dev tools, do you see the parameters in the details? Is the Content-Type header set correctly?

Comment: @CBroe I have just updated the code so that you can see the apiService file which contains addUser.

Comment: @CBroe The application is being directly tested on my phone using Expo. As a reminder, I have developed the website which works perfectly fine. Currently, I am developing the application for this website, which uses the same backend. In the application, all interactions with the API are working except for this one.

Comment: Ah, there we go - you are sending JSON, in which case PHP will _not_ populate $_POST. So either change the client-side part, so that it makes a normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request - or modify your server-side part accordingly, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866571/1427878 (Since you still want it to work when the request comes from the website, the first option would be the more recommendable one.)